# PHP CLI in windows cant access extensions

Tags: php, windows

Using a fresh install of PHP found in C:\Program Files (x86)\php, I edit the php.ini to include a few libraries (I.e. pdo_oci). But when I run the CLI command `php` I get this:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_oci' (tried: ext\
pdo_oci (The specified module could not be found.), ext\php_pdo_oci.dll (Access
is denied.)) in Unknown on line 0
```

And I can say that ext\php_pdo_oci.dll is most certainly there and Everyone has "full control" to the file.

Comment: Try renaming it to pdo_oci.dll

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget you need Oracle client libraries, for example Oracle Instant Client.